# Assign IDs to headings in ACF using functions.php

Tags: functions, filters, advanced-custom-fields

I'm assigning IDs to each heading on my Wordpress site. It works fine for pages where I don't use ACF with the following code snippet in functions.php

```
function auto_id_headings( $content ) {

  $content = preg_replace_callback( '/(\<h[1-6](.*?))\>(.*)(<\/h[1-6]>)/i', function( $matches ) {
    if ( ! stripos( $matches[0], 'id=' ) ) :
      $matches[0] = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ' id="' . sanitize_title( $matches[3] ) . '">' . $matches[3] . $matches[4];
    endif;
    return $matches[0];
  }, $content );

    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'auto_id_headings' );
```

However, this won't pick up headings inside ACFs so I came up with the following solution, which I also added to functions.php

```
function auto_id_headings_acf( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

  $content = preg_replace_callback( '/(\<h[1-6](.*?))\>(.*)(<\/h[1-6]>)/i', function( $matches ) {
    if ( ! stripos( $matches[0], 'id=' ) ) :
      $matches[0] = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ' id="' . sanitize_title( $matches[3] ) . '">' . $matches[3] . $matches[4];
    endif;
    return $matches[0];
  }, $value );

    return $value;

}
add_filter( 'acf/format_value/type=wysiwyg', 'auto_id_headings_acf', 10, 3);
```

It doesn't work though. :/

Any idea what I can do to make it work? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you printing the contents of the ACF field in your site code?

Assuming that you have self-coded theme files, instead of using `the_field()` to print the field content, you should echo `get_field()` passed through the `'the_content'` filter,

eg: `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_field( 'my_field_name' ) );`

and it will apply the modifications from your first snippet.